# Graphiql: The field at path '/greeting/name' was declared as a non null type Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I want to enter a query with a parameter, and get a response in Graphql. I'm sending a request to a spring-boot server and I want to receive a response "Hello, ${name}", But I get an error:

```
        {
            "message": "The field at path '/greeting/name' was declared as a non null type, but the code involved in retrieving data has wrongly returned a null value.  The graphql specification requires that the parent field be set to null, or if that is non nullable that it bubble up null to its parent and so on. The non-nullable type is 'String' within parent type 'Person'",
            "path": [
                "greeting",
                "name"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "classification": "NullValueInNonNullableField"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "greeting": null
    }
}
```

Help me please!
My schemas:

```
type Person{
    name: String
} 
type Query {
    greeting(name: String!): Person
}
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestGraphController {

    @QueryMapping
    public String greeting(@Argument String name){
        System.out.println("\n\nrequest-> " + name);
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }
}
```

My request:

```
query {
  greeting(name: "Test") {
      name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return string as response, you should define the return type as String instead of Person in schema as shown below

```
type Query {
     greeting(name: String!): String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SpringBoot, you need to return such an object that you request in a query in GraphQL

```
@QueryMapping
public Person greeting(@Argument String name){
    System.out.println("\n\nrequest-> " + name);
    Person person = new Person(name);

    return person;
}
```